# get information from other function Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework, pagination, getparameter

I've selected some data and put them in table . It's shown by pagination `(localhost/books/users`)
 
id is primary key and phone and detail is another columns in my table, if user press "detail" , he goes to another page. (`localhost/books/detail/phone`)
I can define what detail for which user in Books controller , but I can't get parameter for each user to fetch his information from database.

Answer (score 1):

Define your route with parameters:

```
$routes['books-details'] = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
        '/books/:id', array(
    'module' => 'books',
    'controller' => 'index',
    'action' => 'details',
    'id' => null
));
```

and add parameters to link:

```
$this->url(array('id'=> $id), 'books-details');
```